# javascript and jQuery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a project where I need to create an animation like carousel, I must always display seven images horizontally and rotate them in a nice way.

My code is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var repite = setInterval(function(){rotateImages();},3000);
  //rotateImages();
});

function rotateImages() {    
  $('ul.rotateImages>li.activo').prev().removeClass( "visible" ).addClass( "activo" );
  $('ul.rotateImages>li.activo').first().next().removeClass( "activo" ).addClass("visible");
  $('ul.rotateImages>li.visible').first().prev().removeClass( "oculto" ).addClass("visible");
  $('ul.rotateImages>li.visible').last().removeClass( "visible" ).addClass("oculto");
  $('ul.rotateImages').prepend($('ul.rotateImages>li:last-child'));
}
```

```css
div.wrapper-animacion-cel {
  display: table;
  margin-top:50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.rotateImages{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.rotateImages>li {
  /*display: inline;*/
  display:table-cell;
  list-style-type: none;
  opacity: .5;
}

.rotateImages>li > img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.rotateImages>li.activo {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-right: -35px;
}

.rotateImages>li.activo > img {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.rotateImages>li.oculto{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-animacion-cel center-block" style="height: inherit;">
 <ul class="rotateImages">
   <li class="oculto"><img src="../images/screen_cel_1.png"/></li>
   <li class="oculto"><img src="../images/screen_cel_2.png"/></li>
   <li class="oculto"><img src="../images/screen_cel_3.png"/></li>
   <li class="oculto"><img src="../images/screen_cel_4.png"/></li>
   <li class="oculto"><img src="../images/screen_cel_5.png"/></li>
   <li class="visible"><img src="../images/screen_cel_6.png"/></li>
   <li class="visible"><img src="../images/screen_cel_7.png"/></li>
   <li class="visible"><img src="../images/screen_cel_8.png"/></li>
   <li class="activo"><img src="../images/screen_cel_9.png"/></li>
   <li class="visible"><img src="../images/screen_cel_10.png"/></li>
   <li class="visible"><img src="../images/screen_cel_11.png"/></li>
   <li class="visible"><img src="../images/screen_cel_12.png"/></li>
   <li class="oculto"><img src="../images/screen_cel_13.png"/></li>
   <li class="oculto"><img src="../images/screen_cel_14.jpg"/></li>
   <li class="oculto"><img src="../images/screen_cel_15.png"/></li>
   <li class="oculto"><img src="../images/screen_cel_16.jpg"/></li>
   <li class="oculto"><img src="../images/screen_cel_17.jpg"/></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The animation of rotation must be smoother than now, but I don't idea of how to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's animations are notoriously slow, and not well suited to things more complicated than slideDown, etc.  Have you considered a different animation library like Tween Lite?

http://greensock.com/tweenlite

Comment: Actually i am new on this, if you recoment me a library i can try it

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion for simple animations are CSS3 transitions, just make sure your target browsers support transitions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

For example, if you changed your code to consistently use one CSS property to rotate your images such as 'left', and then used 'transition: left 0.2s ease-in;' when the targeted elements left positioning changes, the element will 'ease-in' smoothly in that direction over a .2s duration.